# Identify subgroup by field value in MongoDB Aggregation Pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to generate a tally for votes on a model called a link using the MongoDB Aggregation Pipeline.

My vote model has a "linkID" field, which is a foreign key for the link being voted on, and a "liked" field, which is either 1 or 0 and indicates either a positive or negative vote. What I would like to return, is a document for each link that has a field called "yesVotes" with the total number of votes with "liked" value 1, and "noVotes" with total number of value 0.

Currently I have:

```
Vote.aggregate([
{ $group:
  {
    _id: {link: "$linkID", rating: "$liked"},
    count: { $sum: 1 }
  }
},
{ $group:
  {
    _id: "$_id.link",
    votes: {
      $addToSet: { rating: "$_id.rating", count: "$count"}
    }
  }
}
]);
```

which returns something like this for each link:

```
  {
    "_id": "5d464628908dbf00072daa11",
    "votes": [
      {
        "rating": 0,
        "count": 1
      },
      {
        "rating": 1,
        "count": 2
      }
    ]
  }
```

But this makes no differentiation between yes votes and no votes and also returns them in no defined order. I could sort them, but there's no guarantee there will be both yes votes and no votes on any single link.

How can I return fields that specifically have the count for votes with value 0 or 1, respectively?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Can do it in a much simpler way using [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/):

```
Vote.aggregate([
  { $group:
    {
      _id: { link: "$linkID" },
      yesVotes: { $sum: { $cond: { if: { $eq: ["$liked", 1] }, then: 1, else: 0 }}},
      noVotes: { $sum: { $cond: { if: { $eq: ["$liked", 0] }, then: 1, else: 0 }}}
    }
  }
]);
```

This returns:

```
  {
    "_id": {
      "link": "5d5b30fa4d607f0007715683"
    },
    "yesVotes": 3,
    "noVotes": 0
  },
```